# Do iPhone App Updates Contain the Whole App or only a "Delta" (e.g. files that changed)

Tags: iphone

I'm considering including some large movies in my app, but I don't want users to have to re-download the movies each time they get an update. When a user downloads an update from the app store, do they end up re-downloading the entire bundle? Or only parts of the app that have changed relative to their version (i.e. do updates only ship some sort of binary patch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole app.  iTunes actually stores multiple versions of all your apps, and they are submitted to Apple as zipped app bundles.

Comment: Newer versions of iTunes drop old versions of apps that have been updated into the Trash.

Answer (score 0):

The whole bundle, as submitted to, tested, approved and codesigned by Apple.

iTunes will delete any previous versions of your app.

If you have very large content that you don't want installed on every update, you might want to consider allowing users to download it from a website for offline use, and have the app store it in the app's sandboxed Documents directory, which should survive app updates (baring weird update bugs).

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that large apps take a while to update. There are many ways Apple could theoretically implement a diff (and it's probably advantageous for them to offer a diff between the two latest versions, since it reduces their bandwidth bill), but as far as I know, they don't.

"Large" apps (>20 MB, currently) can only be downloaded over Wi-Fi. If you make your app big enough, that means users won't download the update until they get connected over Wi-Fi. Also consider that existing users have already paid you — I don't advocate screwing over your users (if only because they'll leave bad reviews), but taking a while to update apps isn't a big deal; that can happen as I sleep.

I'd worry about new users/initial installs:

- New users won't be able to download your app unless they're connected over Wi-Fi. I'm not sure what the difference in sales figures is — I can't see it in our graphs (so under 10%?), but it probably depends on the type of app.
- A lengthy initial install leaves a bad impression: They've never used your app before. They just found it on the App Store, decided it was worth buying/installing.... and now they have to wait.

If you don't mind running your own servers, then it's definitely worth considering.